# What is the purpose of a reduce task when inserting data into a partitioned Hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce

I have a non partitioned table named stocks_A which only has stocks that start with character A (of size 388 MB on HDFS as 20 small files)

I am inserting all these from stocks_A into a partitioned table named stocks_symFirstChar using below Hive (3.1.2 and MR engine) insert command. Both tables have same row,file formats

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE stocks_symFirstChar
PARTITION (symFirstChar='A')
SELECT * FROM stocks_A;
```

Below are the execution details:

MapReduce Jobs Launched:

- Stage-Stage-1: Map: 3  Reduce: 2   Cumulative CPU: 46.61 sec   HDFS Read: 407726735 HDFS Write: 401037838 SUCCESS
- Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 46 seconds 610 msec

My query is: **What is the purpose a reduce task here? Shouldn't this be a map only job?**

Also, with 2 reducers, I was expecting 2 files in the partition directory. But there are 3 files!

Comment: A reducer can be used to filter the data, while the mapper just processes the original files as-is. Regarding number of files, that's really determined by blocksize more than the task amount. In any case, you should really be using Tez with Hive, and not Mapreduce